# How can I block select multiple lines of code in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, selection, code-formatting

My question today is, when selecting multiple lines of code and not completely selecting the full line for all the lines selected, **how can I** (or is there any keyboard shortcut for) **block select all the lines that I have already selected, so that** I have not just some lines fully selected and some not fully selected, but **all the lines are fully selected from the home of the top line selected, to the end of the last line selected?**

> **Note**: The bold text in the segment above is what I am mainly trying to ask.

Thanks to anybody that is able to provide me with any helpful information!

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like you want to select a block and not the complete line.

Hold the alt key and use the mouse to select your block.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I am wondering is there any way that you could have some lines selected but not fully, then click some shortcut to select the full lines for all the lines you have selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alt + Shift + Arrow keys..
Its called Box Selection and was introduced in VS2010.
learn more about it [here](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/10/box-selection-visual-studio-editor.html)